# ¿Cómo usar el StarActivityForResult? Error StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, activity

Soy nuevo en el entorno de desarrollo de java y aun mas en android studio,el tema es el siguiente:

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con 2 activities, en la primera tengo un TextView(en el cual aparecera el valor de un contador) y un boton el cual al presionarlo tiene que invocar a la segunda activity.

La segunda activity tiene 3 botones: incrementar, decrementar y cancelar. Al presionar el primero tiene que volver a la activity 1 y mostrar un incremento de +1 en el TextView, con el boton 2 un decremento -1  y con el ultimo solo tiene que volver la activity 1.

Esta es la activity 1

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView t;
int contador = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void Cambiar(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

    startActivityForResult(i,5);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    this.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    int c = resultCode;
    if (c == 1){
        contador++;
    }else if (c == 2 ){
        contador--;
    }
    t.setText(contador);
}
}
```

y la activity 2 es la siguiente:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}

protected void incrementarValor(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    setResult(1);
    this.finish();
}
protected void decrementarValor(View v){
    setResult(2);
    this.finish();
}
protected void cancelarValor(View v){
    setResult(3);
    this.finish();
}
}
```

La aplicación al presionar sobre cualquiera de los 2 botones se traba y se cierra, disculpen si hay algún error grosero, soy un novato todavía. El error que aparece es el siguiente:

> Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError

PD: se que no necesito llaves si el el código dentro del if es de una sola linea, pero ya estoy acostumbrado.

---

primero que nada modifique un detalle muy obvio que es que en `onActivityResult` estaba haciendo una llamada recursiva con `this`. lo cambie por `super`.

al cambiar eso ahora no se cierra en el emulador, sino lo que pasa es que cambia de la activity 2 a la 1 pero con un leve retardo, pero no aumenta el contador

Otra cosa que me di cuenta con un `Toast` es que el valor de `resultCode` es `0`, cambie la comparación en el `if` y lo que pasa es que al intentar pasar de la activity 2 a la 1 se cierra y salta este error en el log

> 04-26 19:02:41.158 10878-10878/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio, PID: 10878
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity
>   {com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3429)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=5, result=0, data=null} to activity
>   {com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:34)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3403) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)  04-26
>   19:02:41.166 10878-10878/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 10878 SIG: 9

Dejando el 5 en el metodo me quedaria de esta forma:

```
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    int c = resultCode;
    if (c == 0){
        int valor = data.getExtras().getInt("val");
        contador= contador + valor;
        t.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
    }
}
```

El log al volver a la activity 1 es esto:

> 04-26 19:12:11.055 22414-22414/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 04-26 19:12:11.082 22414-22431/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes
>   (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.082 22414-22431/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.082 22414-22431/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Instrumentation
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.315 22414-22414/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced
>   unknown path: /data/app/com.example.seba_12z.ejercicio-2/lib/arm
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.460 22414-22414/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method
>   android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.708 22414-22447/? I/Adreno-EGL:
>   : QUALCOMM Build: 10/09/15, 6cbbf7d,
>   I3193f6e94a
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.713 22414-22447/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL,
>   version 1.4
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.713 22414-22447/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
>
> 04-26 19:12:11.776 22414-22414/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int
>   android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int,
>   boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method
>   in android.widget.ListView

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que aparece en el log?

Comment: me aparece esto D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: edita tu pregunta [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/65711/edit) y añade el error, te debe aparecer la linea del error en la consola

Comment: SE bastian cambia a   t.setText(String.valueOf(contador)); dentro de   t.setText(String.valueOf(contador)); @sebaz

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera correcta de hacer esto, y también es una buena practica, te recomiendo que lo hagas así:

Cuando inicias un actividad esperando el resultado, lo haces así:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Origen.this, Destino.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 5);
```

Te recomiendo cambiar ese **5** por un valor estatico definido en el Activity Destino, por ejemplo:

```
public static final Integer ID = 5;
```

Entonces la manera de invocar ese activity sería:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Origen.this, Destino.class);
startActivityForResult(i, Destino.ID);
```

Ahora lo que tienes que hacer es sobrescribir al método onActivityResult en la actividad padre:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Si te fijas bien tienes 3 parametros en este metodo:

**requestCode**: Sirve para identificar la actividad que de la cual proviene el resultado (Anteriormente fue Destino.ID (5)).

**resultCode: (Ojo) Sirve para identificar si el resultado del Activity lanzado fue existoso**

**data: (Ojo) Mediante este intent se pueden extraer datos del Activity lanzado, como por ejemplo si el usuario selecciono Incrementar Valor o Decrementar Valor**

Dicho esto manos a la obra:

Lo primero es verificar que el resultCode corresponde al ID de tu Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == Destino.ID){

    }
}
```

Posteriormente vas a verificar el resultado de tu actividad fue correcto o incorrecto, para ello:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == Destino.ID){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //Resultado correcto!!

        }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            //El usuario cancelo
        }
    }
}
```

Observa que los valores **RESULT_OK** y **RESULT_CANCELED** provienen de la clase Activity, no tienes que declararlos.

En el activity Destino vas a enviar el resultado de la acción del usuario:

```
public class Destino extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final Integer ID = 5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.Destino);
    }

    protected void incrementarValor(View v) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        this.finish();
    }

    protected void decrementarValor(View v) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        this.finish();
    }

    protected void cancelarValor(View v) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Mediante **setResult** estas estableciendo el resultado de la Actividad.

Ya puedes identificar si el usuario selecciono cancelar, pero aun no puedes distinguir entre Incrementar y Decrementar, para hacer esto necesitas crear un Intent y enviarlo al Activity padre:

```
public class Destino extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final Integer ID = 5;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.Destino);
    }

    protected void incrementarValor(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("op","Incrementar");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        this.finish();
    }

    protected void decrementarValor(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("op","Decrementar");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        this.finish();
    }

    protected void cancelarValor(View v) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Finalmente para evaluar esta operación en el Activity padre:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Destino.ID) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //Resultado correcto!!
            if(data.getStringExtra("op").equals("Incrementar")){
                //Usuario selecciono Incrementar

            }else if(data.getStringExtra("op").equals("Decrementar")){
                //Usuario selecciono Decrementar

            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //El usuario cancelo
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque cuando inicias el activity 2, lo haces así:

```
startActivityForResult(i,5);
```

Por lo tanto el código(resultCode) es 5, y tú no lo estas considerando en el onActivityResult, modificalo

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    this.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    int c = resultCode;
    if (c == 5){ //  código 5
        int valor = data.getIntExtra("val");
        contador = contador + valor;
        t.setText(contador);
    }
}
```

y en la activity 2 tienes que devolver el valor mediante una variable(int) en un intent:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
}

protected void incrementarValor(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("val",1);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}
protected void decrementarValor(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("val",-1);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}
protected void cancelarValor(View v){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("val",0);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
}
}
```

Comment: En el metodo de onActivityResult a valor le tengo que asignar int valor = data.getExtras().getInt("val"); porque de otra forma me da error, pero sigue teniendo el mismo problema, me fije en los errores y tambien me aparece esto Error: ERR: method=onActivityResult line=28 y tambien me sale este mensaje: too much output to process

Comment: pero pon todo el error, lo que pones es muy generico y no dice nada

Comment: No, el 5 que introduce al lanzar la Actividad 2 (startActivityForResult(i,5)) es el requestCode. El resultCode es el valor que le asigna en el setResult(valor, intent) de la Actividad 2.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t;
    int contador = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Cambiar(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);

        startActivityForResult(i,5);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode==5){
            if(resultCode==1)
                contador=contador+1;
            if(resultCode==2)
                contador=contador-1;
            t.setText(""+contador);
        }
    }
}
```

y en la actividad 2 la tienes prácticamente bien, lo que pasa que al hacer el setResult tienes que añadir el intent, aunque no lo uses luego.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    Intent i = new Intent();
    protected void incrementarValor(View v){

        setResult(1, i);
        this.finish();
    }
    protected void decrementarValor(View v){
        setResult(2, i);
        this.finish();
    }
    protected void cancelarValor(View v){
        setResult(3, i);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Prueba así y nos cuentas si te ha funcionado o te falla (y si te falla indica que fallo te da ahora).

Answer (score -1):

> D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError

Estas llamamando un mismo metodo varias veces en `onActivityResult()`.

```
               @Override
                protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    //* incorrecto!!!               
    //this.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    //* Correcto     
super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

           ...
           ...
```

---

Otro error dentro de `onActivityResult()` , Al agregar un valor en el `TextView` mediante `setText()`, este debe ser de tipo String, debes convertirlo:

```
 // t.setText(contador);
 t.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
```

---

Conforme editas tu código estas creando otros detalles que no tienen que ver con la pregunta original.

Al regresar a MainActivity, este es el problema:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.os.Bundle
>
> android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference at

Se debe a que el intent tiene un valor null, te recomiendo validar y asegurar el intent contenga los datos requeridos

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    int c = resultCode;
    if (c == 0){
          if(data!=null){
          int valor =    data.getExtras().getInt("val");
          contador= contador + valor;
          t.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
         }
    }
```

Comment: El método setText de los objetos TextView permiten introducir int, double, float... sin tener que pasarlos a String, eso sí, si luego pretendes recuperar ese valor del TextView sí que te lo va a devolver en formato texto.

Comment: Agrega un entero dentro del método setText() , te sugiero pruebes tu mismo. @PabloSimondi

Comment: Rectifico (que dicen que es de sabios y así me echo flores) tiene razón @Jorgesys, sólo permite Strings, aunque me parece una cagada

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, de hecho no se en que caso pudiera usar el usar un id, debería internamente cambiar el valor a String. Bueno, seguramente por esa razón alguién me dio el -1.